# Java move jlabel in animation every 0.5 second

Tags: java, animation, jlabel, wait, move

I want simple animation to set location every 0.5 second but it doesnt animate only set location at the end of the loop.

int x=1;
    int y=1;

```
while(x<100){

jLabel1.setLocation(x, y);

x=x+10;
y=y+10;
try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){}

}
```

I have tried drawing animation with thread.sleep() and it worked, it was animated correctly but unfortanly that is not option for me as i need to move jlabel around frame wich has figure picture inside it.
Can someone pls help me with this problem.

i have tried with this two same result

```
jLabel1.setBounds(x, y, jLabel1.WIDTH,jLabel1.HEIGHT);  //not working 
jLabel1.move(x,y);  //not working
```

Comment: I have tried use Swing Timer but problem is i cannot get it to work inside loop, outside lop it does animate but i want it inside and make timer stop when certan if case is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [Java Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that is more suitable for Swing application.

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Find a sample code [How to fix animation lags in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701688/how-to-fix-animation-lags-in-java/23701990#23701990)