# Painting on a JPanel inside a JScrollPane doesn't paint in the right location

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, draw

So I have a `JPanel` that's inside a `JScrollPane`.
Now I am trying to paint something on the panel, but it's always in same spot.
I can scroll in all directions but it's not moving. Whatever I paint on the panel does not get scrolled.

I already tried:

1. A custom `JViewPort`
2. switching between Opaque = true and Opaque = false

Also I considered overriding the `paintComponent` method of the panel but that would be really hard to implement in my code.

```
public class ScrollPanePaint{

public ScrollPanePaint() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    //I tried both true and false
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //To redraw the drawing constantly because that wat is happening in my code aswell because
    //I am creating an animation by constantly move an image by a little
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            while(true){
                g.fillRect(64, 64, 3 * 64, 3 * 64);
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ScrollPanePaint();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The mistake I make is probably very easy to fix, but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Why it is hard to implement the `paintComponent()` method on `JPanel`?

Comment: Because the all my drawing code would have to be inside the JPanels paintComponent method. An I need to draw on it from other subroutines. Like my entity class that draws the entity on the JPanel cannot be inside the paintComponent method. Or I might be doing things really silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to implement the `paintComponent()` on `JPanel`?

Override `getPreferredSize()` method instead of using `setPreferredSize()`

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // your custom painting code here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(40, 40);
    }
};
```

Some points:

1. Override [JComponent#getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) instead of using `setPreferredSize()`

   Read more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
2. Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of [Java Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that is more suitable for Swing application.

   Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
3. Set default look and feel using [UIManager.setLookAndFeel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel%28java.lang.String%29)

   Read more [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
4. [How to fix animation lags in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701688/how-to-fix-animation-lags-in-java/23701990#23701990)

Comment: Still looking for how to implement this code into my game, but it certainly does what I want it to do. Thanks :)

Comment: So usefull links aswell. Thank you again.

Comment: Sounds good. Welcome you. Don't forget to close the thread if the issue is resolved.

Comment: By clicking on the green right mark in the answer. :) Take [2 minute tour of StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. I finally found a way to implement this code. And it finally works as expected. Thank you so much!! :).