# How stop object in TimerTask?

Tags: java, swing, timertask

I have 6 objects in the class GUI which are moving through the code:

```
Anim anim = new Anim();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(anim, 30, 30);
```

When an object comes to a point I want to stop it. In class Anim I'm doing:

```
public class Anim extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (t1.x == 300 && t1.y == 300) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

It stops application, and I want have stayed at a concrete object. How to do it?

**EDIT:**

Ok, now it works well, does not interfere with other objects. But the object is moving on and after 1 second back to the starting position. I wish the whole time he was in the same position when a sleep.

```
if (Main.auto1.x == 700 && Main.auto1.y == 350) {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Main.auto1.x = 700;
                Main.auto1.y = 350;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
```

Comment: Are you using Swing application?

Comment: @Braj Yes, I using Swing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep()` and [Java Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) in a Swing application that sometime hangs the Swing applicaion.

Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Sample code:

```
private Timer timer;
...
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

       //do what ever you want to do
       // call timer.stop() when the condition is matched
         
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

---

#### EDIT

Please have a look at my another post [How to fix animation lags in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701688/how-to-fix-animation-lags-in-java/23701990#23701990)

Comment: I changed the class Anim on:

    public class Anim extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       if (t1.x == 300 && t1.y == 300) {{
   timer = new javax.swing.Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        timer.stop();

       }
   });
    ...
    ...
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();

But not performed any pause. Where am I now set paused, for example 5 seconds?

Comment: It would be great if you can share a reproducible code.

Comment: Ok, now it works well, does not interfere with other objects. But the object is moving on and after 1 second back to the starting position. I wish the whole time he was in the same position when a sleep.

    if (Main.auto1.x == 700 && Main.auto1.y == 350) {
   timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Main.auto1.x = 700;
        Main.auto1.y = 350;
       }
   });
   timer.setRepeats(false);
   timer.start();

Comment: Instead of comment why don't add it in your original post as an EDIT as I did. Is it readable in comment?

Comment: How to fix the car started to get the vehicle from the place where you were stopped and out of this where he were without timer?

Comment: you have stored the coordinate some where in the code. Just use it and don't reset it.